# JPA Criteria API - Populate associations

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I'm trying to use the JPA Criteria API to do a very easy query.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Person implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_PERSON") 
   private String personCode;

   @Column(name = "NAME")   
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
   List<Address > addresses;

   ... other attributes, getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_ADDRESS")
   private String addressCode;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "COD_PERSON")
   private Person person;

   @Column(name = "street") 
   private String street;

   @Column(name = "zipCode")    
   private String zipCode;

   ... other attributes, getters and setters
}
```

We have defined a ManyToOne association in 'Address' entity, and a OneToMany association in 'Person' entity. Both are defined as lazy because of perfomance issues.

Then I would like for example to query people who lives in a certain zip code. And I would like to get people populated with their addresses.

Because we have defined associations as lazy, and because 'addresses' is a OneToMany association, I think I should use "eclipselink.batch" hint.

I have tried with:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> from = query.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, Address> join =  from.join("addresses");
query.select(from);
Predicate predicate = cb.equal(join .get("zipCode"), "28020");
query.where(predicate);
List results = em.createQuery(query).setHint(org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.BATCH, "p.addresses").getResultList();
```

I get all the people who live in a certain zip code, that's ok, but 'addreses' attribute is not populated.

How could I get 'person' entities populated with 'addreses' attribute?

Thanks

THE SOLUTION I HAVE FOUND:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> from = query.from(Person.class);
    Join<Person, Address> join =  (Join<Person, Address>) from.fetch("addresses", JoinType.LEFT);
    query.select(from);
    Predicate predicate = cb.equal(join.get("zipCode"), "28020");       
    query.where(predicate);
    List results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

What I don't like very much is the casting I have to do. I've tried it with EclipseLink provider. I don't know if it would work with other providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "fetch" method on "Root" class.

For example,

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery q = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
Root o = q.from(Order.class);
o.fetch("items", JoinType.INNER);
q.select(o);
q.where(cb.equal(o.get("id"), orderId));

Order order = (Order)this.em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult();
```

Also, you can check other options from here

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/

Edit 1:

You can do fetch join that results in only one join like below

```
...
Join<Order, OrderItem> join = (Join<Order,OrderItem>)root.<Order,OrderItem>fetch("items");
...
```

Edit 2:

If you don't want to use casting, you can use entity graphs. But this solution is available since JPA 2.1

```
...
EntityGraph<Order> fetchGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Order.class);
fetchGraph.addSubgraph("items");
TypedQuery<Order> orderQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
orderQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", fetchGraph);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have a doubt with your example. How could I filter by any attribute of the 'item' entity? In my case, I have to filter by zipCode that is an attribute of the 'joined' entity.

Comment: You don't need to change anything in your code, just fetch the association you need.

Comment: 'fetch' method returns a 'Fetch' type that has not defined the 'get' method. I need the 'get' method to get a javax.persistence.criteria.Expression, needed for building a javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and effort. I have tested your example but the SQL query that is executed is not rigth at all. I can see the address table in the "from" clause twice.

Comment: SELECT ...
FROM PERSONS t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t0 ON (t0.COD_PERSON = t1.COD_PERSON), 
    ADDRESS t2 WHERE ((t2.ZIPCODE = ?) AND (t2.COD_PERSON = t1.COD_PERSON))

Comment: I think that ADDRESS table is added once because of the "fetch" method call, and once because of the "join" method call.

Comment: I've found a solution but I have to do a casting I don't like very much. I have edited my question with the solution.